# Connect ffmpeg to Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compilation, ffmpeg, mingw

I try to connect ffmpeg to visual c++ like [this](http://ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Microsoft-Visual-C_002b_002b), but when I type "./configure --toolchain=msvc" I have this error:

> c99wrap cl is unable to create an executable file.
>
> If c99wrap cl is a cross-compiler, use the --enable-cross-compile
>   option.   Only do this if you know what cross compiling means.
>
> C compiler test failed

config.log:

> WARNING: pkg-config not found, library detection may fail. mktemp -u
>   XXXXXX ./configure: line 728: mktemp: command not found WARNING:
>   Unknown C compiler C:\c99\c99wrap cl, unable to select optimal CFLAGS
>   check_ld cc check_cc BEGIN /tmp/ffconf..ZHENYA.500.5884.c
>       1 int main(void){ return 0; } END /tmp/ffconf..ZHENYA.500.5884.c C:\c99\c99wrap cl -c -o /tmp/ffconf..ZHENYA.500.5884.o
>   /tmp/ffconf..ZHENYA.500.5884.c fatal error C1510: Cannot load language
>   resource clui.dll. C compiler test failed.

What's the problem? **Or just send me files that you got after compilation with this (I would not have asked, but I fix this two months)**:

> ./configure --toolchain=msvc
>
> make
>
> make install

---

log after changes:

```
   WARNING: pkg-config not found, library detection may fail.
mktemp -u XXXXXX
Uxplas
check_ld cc
check_cc
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.WcAVdgRZ.c
    1   int main(void){ return 0; }
END /tmp/ffconf.WcAVdgRZ.c
c99wrap cl -nologo -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -Dinline=__inline -FIstdlib.h -Dstrtoll=_strtoi64 -c -Fo /tmp/ffconf.jQtxnkfv.o /tmp/ffconf.WcAVdgRZ.c
ffconf.WcAVdgRZ.c
ffconf.jQtxnkfv.o_converted.c
c99wrap link -o /tmp/ffconf.sPZUPuMJ.exe /tmp/ffconf.jQtxnkfv.o
link: invalid option -- o
Try `link --help' for more information.
C compiler test failed.
```

log from second computer:

```
WARNING: pkg-config not found, library detection may fail.
mktemp -u XXXXXX
./configure: line 749: mktemp: command not found
WARNING: Unknown C compiler c99wrap cl, unable to select optimal CFLAGS
check_ld cc
check_cc
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf..zhenya.500.4036.c
END /tmp/ffconf..zhenya.500.4036.c
c99wrap cl -I/local/include -c -o /tmp/ffconf..zhenya.500.4036.o /tmp/ffconf..zhenya.500.4036.c
./configure: line 749: c99wrap: command not found
C compiler test failed.
```

Errors:

```
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2028: ёё√ыър эр эхЁрчЁх°хээє■ ыхъёхьє (0A000039) "void __cdecl av_register_all(void)" (?av_register_all@@$$FYAXXZ) т ЇєэъЎшш "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ёё√ыър эр эхЁрчЁх°хээ√щ тэх°эшщ ёшьтюы "void __cdecl av_register_all(void)" (?av_register_all@@$$FYAXXZ) т ЇєэъЎшш "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)
1>c:\users\Zhenya\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: эхЁрчЁх°хээ√ї тэх°эшї ¤ыхьхэЄют: 2
```

Comment: @moskito-x I'm sorry to have kept you waiting.
I download mktemp-1.6-2, but I have not found mktemp.exe.
After that I tried to compile files (in folder mktemp-1.6) using msys, but I get many errors. Where can I find mktemp.exe?
Thanks!

Comment: it's the download with 'bin' in his name . [mktemp-1.6-2-msys-1.0.13-bin.tar.lzma/download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Extension/mktemp/mktemp-1.6-2/mktemp-1.6-2-msys-1.0.13-bin.tar.lzma/download).

Comment: @moskito-x  I do what you say, but I still get this error

Comment: what error ? mktemp: command not found ?

Comment: @moskito-x c99wrap cl is unable to create an executable file. 

If c99wrap cl is a cross-compiler, use the --enable-cross-compile option. Only do this if you know what cross compiling means. 

C compiler test failed

Comment: and you have downloaded the new : c99-to-c89 : described in my answer ?

Comment: @moskito-x yes, and I do this too

Comment: In which directory, you have copied the 3 files ?

Comment: @moskito-x In Visual Studio 2008\VC\bin,if you about c99wrap.exe, c99conv.exe and makedef

Comment: look at your config.log, if there is any difference to your first post, you should put the new output under your question.

Comment: @moskito-x I put new log in question, but it has not changed much

Comment: please show me content of `ffmpeg\version.h`

Comment: @moskito-x #define FFMPEG_VERSION "1.2.1"

Comment: look at my updated answer.

Comment: hm... sorry, but I don't see any file that you named in these folders

Comment: It's in the link that you show in your question, described exactly! So please do it.

Comment: @moskito-x I tried to install YASM, but after that I had only yasm.exe in my VC\bin. I just can use --disable-yasm.

Comment: Download [vsyasm-1.1.0-win32.zip](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/releases/vsyasm-1.1.0-win32.zip) . From [http://yasm.tortall.net/Download.html](http://yasm.tortall.net/Download.html)

Comment: @moskito-x I copy vsyasm.exe, vsyasm.props, vsyasm.targets and vsyasm.xml in ffmpeg and vc/bin, but still get this error. Log is not changed

Comment: What about `inttypes.h` ?

Comment: @moskito-x I have stdint.h and inttypes.h in ffmpeg

Comment: just to be sure. ! To set up a proper environment in MSYS, you need to run msys.bat from the Visual Studio command prompt !! and `Msys\1.0\bin` is first in your path.

Comment: @moskito-x Yes, I run msys.bat from the VS. But I don't understand the second sentence

Comment: Is `C:\msys\1.0\bin` in your path environment variable ? Best at first position !

Comment: @moskito-x Yes, I have this path in variable, and now on first position. Now the log has changed, I put it in the question

Comment: What do you get, in msys cmd, with the command `link --version`

Comment: @moskito-x link <gnu coreutils> 5,97

Comment: Go to msys\1.0\bin and rename `link.exe` to `linkxx.exe`. What do get with `--version` now ?

Comment: @moskito-x "command not found"

Comment: I mean `link --version` (I thought you know that) if you get Command not found  , "Visual Studio 2008\VC\bin" , is not in your PATH !!

Comment: @moskito-x, I checked the PATH variable, but I had set the path "Visual Studio 2008\VC\bin", I still get "link: command not found", maybe it's because I renamed link.exe to linkxx.exe?

Comment: I do not know, the real path to your "VC\bin" folder, I have shown only a placeholder `Visual Studio 2008\VC\bin` . Of course you need to replace the placeholder with the actual path to Visual Studio !! for example `c:\programs\Visual Studio 80\VC\bin` . :-)

Comment: Than look in that `bin` folder for `link.exe` .

Comment: look in the `c:\programs\Visual Studio 80\VC\bin` folder. There must be a link.exe.

Comment: @moskito-x Yes, I have

Comment: That means, in your path environment variable `c:\programs\Visual Studio 80\VC\bin` does not exist. `link.exe` would otherwise be found. Please give me the exact path to your visual studio. It is quite cumbersome to always point out that you should replace the placeholder with your correct path.

Comment: @moskito-x I installed mingw and msys to the new computer and tried to compile ffmpeg, but I still get the error. I put the log from the new computer in question. I have mingw/bin, msys/bin and vc/bin in the path. I am sure that I did something mistake at the stage of installation! 

1. Can you give a link to the detailed manual for installing mingw and msys?

2. Or how I can compile ffmpeg for visual studio without mingw?

3. Or, best of all, a link to ffmpeg that I can use with visual studio 2008/2010/2012?
Thanks for long-term assistance!

Comment: First Old Computer 1.) Please show me the exact path environment content. 2.) exact path to Visual studio. 3.) exact path to msys. e.g. `C:\msys\1.0\bin` !!

Comment: @moskito-x 1)"C:\msys\1.0\bin;A:\Visual Studio 2008\VC\bin;A:\Visual Studio 2012\VC\bin;C:\opencv\build\x86\vc9\bin\;C:\opencv\build\common\tbb\ia32\vc9\;C:\c99";
2)"A:\Visual Studio 2012(A:\Visual Studio 2008)";
3)"C:\msys(bin - C:\msys\1.0\bin)";

Comment: @moskito-x partition in which the visual studio

Comment: I'm not sure that the drive-letter `A:` is a good choice to install Visual Studio. But let us try with following Path-environment-value. `C:\msys\1.0\bin;"A:\Visual Studio 2008\VC\bin";"A:\Visual Studio 2012\VC\bin"; ....` . Don't put `"` at the beginning and at the end. Only to quote path with spaces.

Comment: @moskito-x oh my god...I think that's progress... I put path of visual studio in quotes and (1) run "./configure --toolchain=msvc" without errors(!)(but i get warning: pkg-config not found, library detection may fail).
2) After that I run "make" and get many warnings(many of c4005, c4133, c4054, c4090, c4245, c4701, c4189), fatal error LNK1181(about "libavfilter/x86volume.o") and "[libavfilter/libavfilter.a]  Error 157".

Comment: @moskito-x 3) Next I run "make install" and get warnings too(c4116, c4700, c4701, c4702, c4703), fatal error LNK1181(about "libavfilter/x86volume.o") and "[libavfilter/libavfilter.a]  Error 157".

Comment: Try to install `pkg-config` [How to pkg-config](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA/mingw_how_to.html#pkg-config). use  instead of all `mingw\bin` the `msys\1.0\bin` .

Comment: @moskito-x I copy pkg-config.exe and liglib-2.0-0.dll into msys/bin.
After that I run "cd C:/msys/bin", "cp libintl-8.dll intl.dll" and get "cp: cannot stat 'libintl-8.dll': No such file or directory".
I copy libintl-8.dll from mingw/bin to msys/bin and successfully run "cp libintl-8.dll intl.dll". Ran ./configure without pkg-config warning

Comment: How far you come with make now ?

Comment: @moskito-x output:"vsyasm: warning: unrecognized option '-M'; YASM libavfilter/x86/af_volume.o; AR libvfilter/libavfilter.a; LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "libavfilter/x86volume.o"; make: *** [libavfilter/libavfilter.a] Error 157"

Comment: @moskito-x I do what you say, but I get: no such file or directory(I have only bin, doc, licenses and presets folders)

Comment: sorry try  : [ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2](http://www.moskito-x.de/stack/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2).

Comment: You have another ffmpeg version so it's hart to help. Rename your ffmpeg folder to ffmpeg-old create a new folder ffmpeg extract the files into that. TAKE CARE : don't forget to copy all the stuff like vsyasm files : inttypes.h : stdint.h and all the other files to the new ffmpeg folder. run ./configure again. let's see how far we come.

Comment: @moskito-x  I run "make" and get many warnings(many of c4005, c4133, c4054, c4090, c4245, c4701, c4189), "fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "libavfilter/x86volume.o" and "[libavfilter/libavfilter.a] Error 157"

Comment: Can you copy the vsyasm files to visual 2012 bin folder. Remove for short time the path enviroment Visual 2008 part. Then you start the visual studio 2012 command start msys.bat cd to ffmpeg run ./configure again.

Comment: and also copy c99wrap.exe : c99conv.exe : makedef to visual studio 2012/bin. And give me the size of `configure` file.

Comment: @moskito-x again have :"vsyasm: warning: unrecognized option '-M'; YASM libavfilter/x86/af_volume.o; AR libvfilter/libavfilter.a; LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "libavfilter/x86volume.o"; make: *** [libavfilter/libavfilter.a] Error 157"; confige size = 148 kB

Comment: configure file in bytes not KB

Comment: @moskito-x 152 077 bytes

Comment: is there a possibility to provide me your `config.log` and `config.mak` on a server? So that I can download and look at those.

Comment: @moskito-x https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4jsXYhk52gaelV6SjdJRjlvODQ&usp=sharing

Comment: As long as I compare the files. Can you try it once with it `./configure --toolchain=msvc --enable-shared` .

Comment: @moskito-x after "make"(if I use ./configure --toolchain=msvc --enable-shared) I get many warnings like c4005, c4133, c4054, c4090, c4245, c4701, c4189 and [libavutil/avutil-52.dll] error 127

Comment: Only for a test if your machine can handle this. Rename your libavutil to libavutilxxx and extract [libavutil.zip](http://www.moskito-x.de/stack/libavutil.zip) . Then run make , to see if we come a little bit further.

Comment: @moskito-x no changes

Comment: 1.) put in your path-variable behind `c:\msys\1.0\bin;` new : `c:\mingw\bin;` remove out of ffmpeg all yasm.* files , not the vsyasm files . 2.) In config.mak about line 26: replace `YASM=yasm` and `DEPYASM=yasm` with `YASM=vsyasm` and DEPYASM=vsyasm` . 3.) Download [unistd.h](http://www.moskito-x.de/stack/unistd.h) and put it into ffmpeg folder. 4.) config.mak about line 399 : `!HAVE_UNISTD_H=yes` remove `!` . run make. Give me more lines from the output !

Comment: @moskito-x I do what you say (by the way, unistd.h has only "/* * This file is part of the Mingw32 package. * * unistd.h maps (roughly) to io.h */ #include ") but still get only that: "vsyasm: warning: unrecognized option '-M'; YASM libavfilter/x86/af_volume.o; AR libvfilter/libavfilter.a; LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "libavfilter/x86volume.o"; make: *** [libavfilter/libavfilter.a] Error 157"

Comment: This is part of the old ./configure , not of the new with `--enable-shared` . Why ?

Comment: I go now , come back in 15 ours. Please copy the path-variable the whole line with ctrl-a and ctrl-c and open an editor paste the content in the editor. Now look there are many double values. Clear the wrong content amd don't forget : path with spaces to quote ! then put the cleared content back to the path-variable. bye

Comment: @moskito-x when I run ./configure with --enable-shared I get warnings too, the last of them: [libavutil/avutil-52.dll] error 127.
I deleted everything except C:\mingw\bin;C:\msys\1.0\bin;"A:\Visual Studio 2012\VC\bin", but nothing changed. **Can you send compiled ffmpeg files ready for use in visual studio, because tonight I'm going out of the city and I will not be able to get online for a long time, but I need this files for work in visual studio. Thanks!**

Comment: ok i put my lib's and dll's in a zip. But i need the output before the error `[libavutil/avutil-52.dll] error 127` .

Comment: @moskito-x https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4jsXYhk52gaamluOUJXWk5KUmc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You have no perl.exe installed !!! And put `c:\mingw\bin` after `c:\msys\1.0\bin` . Install `Active Perl` .

Comment: @moskito-x https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4jsXYhk52gaaE8yeUozTEdrMm8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: in your path variable look for `C:\Perl\lib;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;` if one of the three , not present place it before `c:\msys\1.0\bin` . And remember if you change the path-variable, you have to close all cmd windows and reopen it. So they have a change to get the new environment.

Comment: @moskito-x **can you send me now ffmpeg for visual studio?** I placed C:\Perl\lib;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin; before c:\msys\1.0\bin, but nothing changed.

Comment: Remember `C:\Perl\bin` are only placeholder . I don't know where you installed perl. And close your msys cmd window. And start Visual Studio cmd new.

Comment: is `strict.pm` in your `c:\Perl\lib` yes or not . If your path variable properly set , Visual Studio 2012 must find `c:\perl\lib\strict.pm` !!!

Comment: where are you ? Is error : `can't locate strict.pm` gone ?

Comment: @moskito-x now I'm not in the city and I haven't msys, mingw, ffmpeg and first pc, so can you send me ffmpeg for visual studio

Comment: @moskito-x Should I add only files from ffmpeg-lib.zip?

Comment: @moskito-x Hello. I added all .lib's in additional dependencies and include .h's, but have problem. Code: av_register_all();. Errors in the question(Sorry for the encoding, I think you will understand error code). Thanks!

Comment: I think it's better you upload a short testprogram , so i can test where it hangs.

Comment: Ok I Download it. so please delete comment with the link to the App. You have forget the part `extern "C" { #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h> ... ` . I have a slightly shortened file here : [cApp1.cpp](http://www.moskito-x.de/stack/cApp1.cpp). INFO : Please ask a new question if you have problems !! 85 Comments are enough. Please delete all not really important comments . I will do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `mktemp: command not found`

Download : [mktemp-1.6-2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Extension/mktemp/mktemp-1.6-2/)

put `mktemp.exe` into your `msys\1.0\bin` .

---

Look in your ffmpeg folder are present ?

- inttypes.h
- stdint.h
- vsyasm.targets
- vsyasm.txt
- vsyasm.xml
- copy vsyasm.txt , vsyasm.xml , vsyasm.exe **to**
- yasm.txt , yasm.xml , yasm.exe

Look in your ... \VisualStudio??\VC\bin folder are present ?

- vsyasm.targets
- vsyasm.txt
- vsyasm.xml
- vsyasm.exe
- copy vsyasm.txt , vsyasm.xml , vsyasm.exe **to**
- yasm.txt , yasm.xml , yasm.exe

so you have both vsyasm and yasm !

---

If in your `config.log` the last line is something like `c99wrap cl ... bad file number`

you should download another `c99-to-c89` .

[get it from here](https://github.com/libav/c99-to-c89/downloads)

Search for previously installed files and delete them .

c99wrap.exe
c99conv.exe
makedef

copy the new files to the Visual Studio bin folder .

now `./configure --toolchain=msvc` should run without problems .

Note :
`make` problem :
Tell me how far you come with make . I'm sure you get an `gawk :  unterminated string` error.

Comment: @user2274492 look for : `c:\msys\1.0\bin\mktemp.exe` . Can you `mktemp.exe` file found?

Comment: @user2274492 : Download [mktemp-1.6-2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Extension/mktemp/mktemp-1.6-2/) and put it into `msys\1.0\bin`

Answer (score 0):

> To build (either c99wrap.exe or FFmpeg/Libav itself), make sure that
>   you’re not using the msys linker, but instead the MSVS linker. For
>   now, temporarily backup /usr/bin/link to someplace so it’s not in your
>   $PATH.

source https://blogs.gnome.org/rbultje/2012/09/27/microsoft-visual-studio-support-in-ffmpeg-and-libav/comment-page-1/#comment-367